# Which form is suitable: "fall" "falling" or "a fall"?

Tags: present-participles, poetry, bare-infinitives

1. I hear a book **fall**.
2. I hear a book **falling**.
3. I hear **a fall** of a book.

Which version is most natural?

Comment: Just to be nit-picky, you probably couldn't hear a book falling (unless you have really good ears).  You would only hear it hit the floor.  So I think 'fall' is most natural/accurate, since you don't hear the ongoing process of falling, just the final thud of impact.

Comment: Thank you. Then, how about these sentences: I hear my father snore, I hear a drummer drum, or hear my sister sing. I don't think these verbs denote any short sounds but written without ing. Do they have different usage different from the OP?

Comment: You can say ......either see a book fall or falling. According to grammar,  for a short action, you can use either the bare infinitive or the present participle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are narrating a story and it goes something like this:
*As I entered the room, I heard the creaking sound of the door being blown open by the wind. The cupboards behind me were covered with dust and there were a few tattered books lying on the shelf. As I stepped forward, I heard a book fall from the shelf.*

If the book is still in the process of falling, you could use 'heard a book falling'.
The third one is a little too exaggerated. We normally don't use 'the fall of' for things like books.
Hope that helped!

Comment: Sorry, you have used the past tense for your example. Can you choose what you would normally say in present when someone drops a book in front of you, fall or falling?

Comment: Hi! If you are seeing the person drop the book in front of you, you'd still use the past tense only: 'I heard a/the book fall' because gravity does things too quickly-much before you report the 'falling' in speech. You can use 'hear' only if it's habitual. In this context, if you use 'I hear a book fall' it means that you regularly hear the book fall(which, as you know, doesn't make sense).'fall' is generally used. (I've removed 'hear' from my answer.)

Comment: Joe - for your specific example of someone dropping a book in front of you, you'd say "fall", unless you could speaka really quickly and say "falling whilst it was still ithe air"...

For Aishwarya's story, if you were in a room and you heard a book fall, you could say to someone with you "I heard a book fall", but not "I hear a book falling" (as the book has finished falling).

However, if you were telling this story to a friend afterwards, you might say "I'm standing in the room and I hear a book fall". The story is in the past but you are talking about a actions as they happened.

Comment: @Steve Ives: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.The action described is over so quickly, that it would have completed before you had the chance to speak. Therefore you'd use the past tense. The most natural expression is:

> I heard a book fall.

For a more literary, dramatic phrase, you could write:

> I heard the fall of a book

but you'd be very unlikely to actually say this.

Comment: Using present tense to describe past events is perfectly fine. [Narration - present tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration#Present_tense) and  [Historical present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) on Wikipedia, [Present tense narrative](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php./Main/PresentTenseNarrative)  on TVTropes

Comment: Yes, but if you heard the noise you wouldn't say to a companion "I hear a book fall". When reciting the events at a later date, you might say "Last week, I'm standing in the hall with John and I hear a book fall.".

Comment: @Kreiri, Thanks. Do you mean using of present tense in conversational context or written, narrative story telling context? If you say both, then how often would people change their tense to present tense for past tense? I would get confused, unless it isn't about story telling.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, you would use "I hear a book fall". Of course, you don't actually hear it fall, you hear it hit the floor, but the presumption that it fell is so strong that the phrase is reasonable, especially if the reason for the fall (did an unknown party/enemy knock it off the shelf?) is important.

If there are many books, and they fall as part of a drawn-out process, you can say "I hear some books falling".

Finally, while books don't make an appreciable noise, some objects do, so you might say "I heard a bomb falling toward my position, so I jumped into my foxhole and prayed."

As Aishwara A R has remarked, "I hear the fall of a book" is unlikely, but it's grammatically correct. Subject to the objection that you don't actually hear the fall, but rather the impact with the floor.